# Why is tension needed to create a wave in a string?

Tags: waves, string, continuum-mechanics

Suppose, a  long straight string is present in vacuum. I oscillate one end of the string with a certain frequency. Shouldn't a wave be formed? If it is formed, what will be the velocity of the wave?

Answer (score 3):

Tension provides a restoring force, which is necessary to have oscillations (like a spring or gravity for pendulums). Otherwise any attempt to excite waves will only produce an inelastic deformation.

However, if the gravity is present, there will be tension created due to the non-zero mass of the string which might be sufficient to have waves.